# How to require a module that already exists on a gem? kind of monkey patching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the `telegram-bot` gem. It has a module called `Telegram`. I want to extend it to add one method as a shortcut for my most common call.

The method I want to create is `Telegram.send_message(text)` with my default configuration.

For doing so I added a `telegram.rb` file on `app/models/telegram.rb` that extend the original module:

```
 module Telegram
    def self.send_message(text, options={})
        #...
    end
 end
```

If on console I run `Telegram.send_message` it says undefined method. If I do `require 'telegram'` the `send_message` method now works, (i guess its not autoloaded as there is module called `Telegram` already (the one on the gem). Now I want to require it on app initialization,

What I first tried is add the require on my `application.rb` but it says `cannot load such file`, because, I guess the load_path does not includes `app/models` yet.

Where I can add the require?

Another alternative would be give it another name, like `TelegramBot`. But I don't like the idea of have `Telegram` and `TelegramBot`.

Other alternative would be add it to the `initializers` instead of `app/models`. But I think that folder is more for settings.

So, what is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 2):

When you run a Rails app in development the default is to automatically reload some files/classes on each request, but this behavior causes issues if you're trying to do things that persist between requests within the autoreloaded folders (i.e., anything under `app`).

In your case, since the `Telegram` constant is already defined, the Rails code responsible for mapping a class name back to a file isn't even triggered, so the file isn't automatically `require`d.

Your suggestion to move this to an initializer is a great idea. This behavior indeed belongs in an initializer.

For what it's worth, you can avoid reopening the `Telegram` class to add your method by creating a mixin:

```
module SpecialShortcut
  def foo
    # ...
  end
end

# config/initializers/telegram_extensions.rb
Telegram.extend(SpecialShortcut)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about `extend` instead of monkey patching, I was just reading this nice article http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/ and did exactly that!